# Meteor - QR Code generation on meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor, qr-code

I have been searching for generating QR Code on Meteor Server.

But so far I have found the libraries which works only on Meteor Client.

So is there any library for Meteor which can generate QR Code on Meteor Server side?

Comment: Why do you need to generate the QR code on the server? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a novice at Meteor and I have NOT TRIED this solution, but it seems plausible.

At the core of Meteor is NodeJS which has many more solutions available than you'll find for Meteor in Atmospheres, including QR code image generation. @Arunoda seems to have "hacked" together a way to run most anything under NPM...

https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm

Once you have that working, you can probably use this handy NodeJS QR Code library...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-npm